# .NET regex decimal numbers

Tags: .net, regex

I have to validate using regex decimal number between 00.00 to 35.35 with following simple assumptions(I am using C#).

1) leading zeros are not required(optional). 
2) 2 decimals are always required.

In other words, it should be a decimal number within a range with 2 decimal points.

Examples of valid numbers are: 0.00, 00.00, .67, 2.89
and should fail on those numbers: 8.9999(4 decimals), 65.00(out of range)

I had no difficulty to validate 2 decimal points but don't know how to do the range?
Is this something that even can be done using regex?

Comment: BTW, it's ".NET regex", not "C# regex". The same regular expressions also work in VB.NET and F#.

Comment: No it's not unfortunately(fortunately?). It's eye treatment application data entry screen

Comment: @John Thanks for edit, John. Yeah, I know, it's a ".NET regex", just didn't state it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(0?\d|[12]\d|3[0-4])?\.\d\d$|^35\.([02]\d|3[05])$
```

Comment: The upper limit is 35.35, so `35.56` should not pass.

Comment: Validating against 35.35 (or any numeric values) should not be done as a part of the regex. It's possible but makes things very sticky and messy.

Comment: @Frustrated Yes, I would agree with that, just by looking at RegEx above.

Answer (score 4):

Seriously. Use RegEx to check that the input matches `^\d{1,2}\.\d{2}$`, then convert it into a number and check `0 <= x && x <= 35.35`. RegEx is not designed to be a calculator.

---

If you insist:

```
^(?:(?:[012]?\d|3[0-4])\.\d{2}|35\.(?:[012]\d|3[0-5]))$
```

Comment: +1  Some people insist on using RegEx to solve everything.  Like using a hammer to paint a picture..Possible, not recommended

Comment: @Cody C: Painting a picture with a hammer could get you praise from some of the more 'creative' contemporary artists out there. Especially if you make a performance out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx). E.g.:

```
    private const decimal min = 0.0M;
    private const decimal max = 35.35M;
    static bool inRange(string s)
    {
        Decimal d = new Decimal();
        if (Decimal.TryParse(s, out d))
        {
            return d > min && d < max;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, that's what I am wondering - is it better to use RegExValidator or just a CustomValidator with method like this.

Comment: @VictorS: I would think this is much better than using a regex, but maybe you are in a situation that REQUIRES a regular expression.

Comment: @VictorS: The other nice thing about this approach is that you can put this functionality into a `DecimalRangeValidator` class and then reuse it for other ranges (if you have them) by parameterizing the max, min, and test value, rather than having to write a new expression for every range you want to test.